# resolve a tree knowing ALL parents and ancestors of leaf nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

It is pretty straighforward to build a tree if you know the immediate parent of all nodes. But what if you have information about ALL parents of the leaf nodes (including grand-parents, great-grand-parent, etc.) without knowing if it is immediate parent or not?

For example consider the following tree:

```
              A ----->  B ------> C -----> G

                       |

                       D ------> E

                       |

                       F
```

The information available to describe this tree is the following CSV file:

child, parent

E,D

E,B

E,A

F,D

F,B

G,C

G,B

G,A

F,A

Could you please give some advice on a general algortihm to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parents(F) = {A,B,D}
parents(E) = {A,B,D}
parents(G) = {A,B,C}
```

It is not possible to recreate **the** tree from this data set because obviously we can't see from that data which node is the root, is it `A` or is it `B`?

Comment: Andreas is right - I thought you had data for all the nodes, not just the leaves.

Comment: If A had other children, you could rebuild the tree so long as child order didn't matter because you could then tell the difference between A and B. As it is, they "look the same."

Comment: Thansk a lot! So I can work out the tree if: 1) Each node is garanteed to have two nodes or 2) I don't care about their order if the node only has one child. Right?